# Why is my php script is not sending email?

Tags: php, html, email

i am trying to send a feedback message to my email address 'iamhamzach@gmail.com', the scripts are running properly and but i have not receiving email. please tell me what is the problem..

html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="email.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="name" value="name" name="name"/><br>
      <input type="text" id="email" value="email" name="email"/><br>
      <input type="text" id="comment" value="comment" name="comment"/><br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

php:

```
<?php


    $emailSubject = 'my first mail';
    $webMaster = 'iamhamzach@gmail.com';

    $emailField = $_POST['email'];
    $nameField = $_POST['name'];
    $commentField = $_POST['comment'];

    $body = <<<EOD
    <br><hr><br>
    Email: $email <br>
    Name: $name <br>
    Comments: $comment <br>
    EOD;

    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

    $theResults = <<<EOD
      <html>
        <body>
          Thank you for your feed back
        </body>
      </html>
    EOD;
    echo "$theResults";

?>
```

Comment: Do you have a mail server properly configured and running on your server box? If not, your mail won't go anywhere.

Comment: What is the response from the SMTP server?

Comment: i have receive no error message and i have checked my server is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most localhosts dont support emailing out of the box.

try to upload this script to your webhost and it should be fine.

the code looks ok.